# Where condition between dates in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql

```
WHERE Customer.LastTranDate BETWEEN 
udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(to_date('2012/01/01 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND    
udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(to_date('2016/01/01 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

The above condition worked perfect for specific dates but I want to check the same condition for a period of 12 months i.e between today's date and date 12 months ago.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
WHERE Customer.LastTranDate BETWEEN 
udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')))
AND 
udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(to_date(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')))
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to switch the dates. `BETWEEN` acts from <start date> to <end date>. You have it the other way around - going backwards through time.

Comment: swapped both and tried too.. It didn't work ...Throwing out error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: What does `udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetodatetime` do?

Answer (score 1):

Huh?  Why all the conversion to and back from strings?

```
WHERE Customer.LastTranDate BETWEEN
          udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(add_months(sysdate, -12)) AND
          udf_functions.udf_oracledatetimetotdatetime(sysdate
```

If the function takes an Oracle `date` as an argument (as suggested by the `to_date()`, then there is no need to convert to strings and back to dates.

I don't really understand why you have a udf to do such conversions.  That can only hurt performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked but I want that in the format of YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS. That's the reason for converting.

Comment: @Cooluser - that makes no sense. A date is either before or after 05/20/2016 16:30:00 or it isn't - it doesn't matter in what format you have the date (as a string) in your mind. What you need to pass in for comparison are dates, not strings; and SYSDATE is already a date, you don't need to give it a format mask to convert it. Perhaps what you mean is you need the format mask if instead of SYSDATE you have **date_column** from a table, and **date_column** is in string format (which it shouldn't be, but it is) and you must give a format mask. That makes sense, but not with SYSDATE.

Answer (score 0):

No need for date conversion on your `WHERE` part of query.

If you need date in specific format, you do that on `SELECT` part, and leave `WHERE` as it is